# selected value in select tag is not working in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to set default value in this select tag. For this I have used "ng-model" and for options, I have used "ng-options" but default value is not selected. So anybody can suggest that what should I do?

Comment: could you provide the html-code and the JavaScript - Code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to know that ng-options compares the Object in ng-model not the value.

Comment: Thanks. You are right and Now it works.